# Ground wire goes nowhere from another property into mine

Tags: wire

I live in a flying freehold and doing a renovation found a yellow and green ground wire that goes nowhere from the property below.Is it safe to cut it?

Comment: Does your building have lightning rods or lightning arrestors?

Comment: "**Goes nowhere**" as in you found an end, and you're absolutely sure you didn't cut it in finding the end? Is the end corroded and green/dark, or somewhat shiny copper? Also, what does a "flying freehold" mean for those of us where that's not a common term?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a lot more info before we can help you. Perhaps a picture of the wire? Any reason why you don't want to avoid the problem by tucking this wire back where it came from?

Comment: @Ecnerwal - from Wikipedia - "Flying freehold is an English legal term to describe a freehold which overhangs or underlies another freehold. Common cases include a room situated above a shared passageway in a semi-detached house, or a balcony which extends over a neighbouring property."

Comment: Sounds like it might "go somewhere" as in to a grounding/ earthing system somewhere below, rather than just to the next thing down the stack.